# Website Container Styles do not apply properly on other hosts

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, apache-http-server, docker

Here's my scenario, I have a host machine which has VirtualBox installed, inside VirtualBox, I have an Ubuntu VM, and a Windows 10 VM. All of the machines, included the host, are on the same LAN network, so they can communicate with each other.

On the Ubuntu VM, I have a container, running Apache, Wordpress and a database.
So, per the container config, everytime you want to access the website, you need to put the LAN IP on the browser and specifying 8081 port, and it will be redirected to the container on port 80 as I have installed a web proxy through Nginx.

On the wordpress settings I was able to set the server name as containerwpress.com. When I access the website through the Ubuntu VM, it looks just fine, but when I access it with the other two Windows 10 hosts, the css styles do not apply properly, and here is what Chrome displays on it's debug console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqVhy.jpg

Is there any reason or something I have to do on server side in order for styles to apply properly on other hosts?

Comment: It would nice to know what exact URLs are used there, and how you serve static content such as CSS..

Comment: I installed Wordpress so I really have almost no knowledge on CSS nor any web language, what do you mean by how I serve the static content? It's a wordpress theme template..

Comment: Dynamic content is what changes depending on user input (text of web pages, user pictures, everything that is added as part of the life of the site), and is generated by the PHP code from data in the database, while static is what is the same everywhere (and exists before the site is even put online): icons, CSS, and is just files. Static and dynamic content are served by different mechanisms (static content can be cached, for instance).